# Глобальная фильтрация $_GET и $_POST данных в PHP

Tags: php

Здравствуйте.

Как лучше всего глобально фильтровать **$_GET** и **$_POST** данные?

Например, определенный код **глобальной фильтрации** в шапку сайта.

Буду благодарен за пример.

Comment: Лучше не фильтровать вообще.

Comment: например $data = stripslashes(strip_tags($_POST["data"]));
практически всегда нужно фильтровать от спец символов, и тегов

Comment: @ChromeChrome, ваш подход неправильный. Фильтровать надо не это.

Comment: автор, зачем вы пытаетесь удалить чужие ответы? Если вы считаете, что вопрос заслуживает удаления - удаляйте именно его. Зачем вы выкидываете в мусорку старания и время других людей? Но мне кажется, учитывая количество голосов, удалять вопрос не стоит.

Answer (score 6):

Если код дырявый, то ему и фильтрация не поможет от взлома :)

Фильтруйте и валидируйте данные по мере необходимости. Вы напишите универсальное решение которое например будет обрезать html теги, а они Вам пригодятся в другом месте. Если хотите защититься от XSS делайте в HTML какие-то определенные разрешенные теги с помощью специальных библиотек.

Используйте, библиотеки для фильтрации данных, которых куча на github. Например, [Filterus](https://github.com/ircmaxell/filterus)

Comment: @Webmaster скажите, а какие цели вы преследуете от глобальной фильтрации? Ее область получается слишком обширна, и чтобы написать универсальное решение нужно знать все входные данные и при такой всеобщей фильтрации ее полезность близиться к нулю. Из общих правил, которые часто используются я знаю, что можно делать trim для всей строки и то это не всегда требуется :)

Answer (score 6):

Объясню почему лучше не фильтровать, был у меня проэкт с фиильтрацией глобально на самописной cms и там все запросы переписывались

типо того

```
foreach($_POST as $_key => $_value) {
   $_POST[$_key] = filter_var($_value,FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);
}

foreach($_GET as $_key => $_value) {
   $_GET[$_key] = filter_var($_value,FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);
}
```

а после этого туча кастылей и багов что бы когда нужно обойти это самое ограничение. Это как объяснение почему не стоит фильтровать так как вы хотите, и дополнение к ответу @Firerepo что нужно фильтровать только когда это необходимо а не всё и вся.

Comment: У вас есть админка, модерация и т.д. не всегда надо удалять спец символы и т.д. короче как пить дать полфункционала отвалиться.

Comment: PSR-2. В списке аргументов НЕ ДОЛЖНО быть пробела перед запятыми, но ДОЛЖЕН быть пробел после каждой запятой.

Answer (score 6):

При возникновении подобных вопросов их очень полезно переводить из непонятного мира программирования в понятные всем реалии обычной жизни. Тогда он будет звучать так:

- Как глобально защититься от всех болезней?

Смешно, да?

Еще смешнее будет ответ. Что у нас помогает от болезней? Мыть руки перед едой, носить шарфик от сквозняка, пить таблетки, делать зарядку...

Ну ок, допустим познакомился ты на вечеринке с девушкой, слово за слово, пришли к тебе домой. Ты, как правильный пионер, делаешь все, чтобы глобально защититься - идешь мыть руки, надеваешь шарфик, делаешь зарядку... а через недельку начинают вдруг выделяться непонятные жидкости из понятного места.

Помогла тебе твоя глобальная защита? Будешь и дальше искать универсальное средство? Теперь в довершение к всему перечисленному будешь ходить на обед в презервативе?

**Или все-таки будешь применять средства защиты адресно** - перед едой мыть руки, перед прогулкой надевать шарфик... ну и так далее.

Если все еще не дошло: Взлом бывает разный. И средства защиты от одного никак не помогают от другого.

Если у тебя введенные пользователем данные выводятся в HTML, то их надо защищать от XSS. Но если это введенный админом код HTML, то такая защита его испортит.
При этом от SQL инъекции она не поможет, но зато испортит данные в БД. При этом   ни защита от XSS, ни от SQL инъекции не поможет, если ты инклюдишь файл, имя которого передается из браузера. А пароль для защиты надо хэшировать. но если захэшировать любые другие данные, то они станут бесполезными.

Ты все еще хочешь свою глобальную защиту?

Comment: Похоже на демагогию. Из этого может следовать также, что давайте не будем использовать firewall, и закрывать порты на сервере, это слишком общая защита. Лучше будем по отдельности каждый сервис настраивать (в общем то одно второму не мешает).

Answer (score 6):

мои пять копеек: 
вы задаете неправильный вопрос и получаете ответ на неправильный вопрос.

1) Да, не надо глобально, по всему сайту фильтровать POST/GET/REQUEST

2) Проблема в том, что ваша задача сформулирована как "фильтровать POST/GET/REQUEST", хотя на самом деле у вас вопрос "как правильно валидировать входящие данные"

3) При этом вопрос звучит так, будто вы используете POST/GET/REQUEST во всех подрядд функциях/методах (иначе зачем вам глобальная фильтрация) - это - **абсолютно недопустимо** для *большого/сложного/важного* сайта.  Это приведет к хаосу в коде, к  костылям, копипасте, и, в конечном итоге к тем же самым проблемам с безопасностью. Это **абсолютно недопустимо** с точки зрения культуры разработки

4) примерный ответ на вопрос как правильно валидировать данные - убедиться, что вы не используете POST/GET/REQUEST и не обращаетесь к ним ни в одной функции, ни в одном методе вашего сайта кроме контроллеров (входных точек)  или, как в симфони - обработчиков запроса. Для одностраничников - кроме нескольких первых строк сайта. Вы **должны** - руками или с помощью функции-обработчика запроса создавать переменные из запроса.  После этого - если вы не используете движок, а делаете самописный велосипед - сделать (стырить из опенсорса) обработчики типичных для вашего сайта случаев - только строчки, только цифры. без спецсимволов. Формат email, формат даты. 
и применять их для переменных, которые передаются вашим контроллерам.

5) правильного ответа на вопрос как "фильтровать глобально" быть не может, но ближе всего, если вы упретесь рогом, будет вариант: создать функцию, которая вызывается **всегда** на всех страницах сайта, анализирует путь, куда пришел запрос и вызывает соответствующие обработчики для нужного пути. Это **кровавый велосипед ада**, но раз вы действуете без фреймворков и не хотите делать абстракции форм с валидаторами - у вас хотя бы будет изолированное от всего остального кода место,  где вы, согласно подходящим для пути правилам валидации фильтруете ввод. После этого вы апдейтите _GET/_POST/_REQUEST и больше никогда их не трогаете нигде, кроме как для вытаскивания переменных.

Comment: можно запретить обрабатывать их по определенным путям. (в ответе написано как), так, чтобы они никогда не попали ни в какую из переменных.  т.е. вы можете сделать так, чтобы  в `news/add/`  в get/post убирались любые, допустим, амперсанды.  `foreach ($_REQUEST as $k=>&$v){ $v = str_replace('&', '', $v); }`я просто к тому, что такие вещи надо делать не глобально, а хоть как-то контролируя и локализуя эти фильтры.